# Run docker with cap-add

Tags: docker

Is this code correct?  I am a beginner in Docker and I got a task to solve. EXPOSE is set to 80, 8080, 8090 in Dockerfile. I noticed that a new interface is being created.

```
docker run -d --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 my_test
```

```
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
8090/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8090
```

It should display something in the browser as localhost.

Comment: please provide some debugging data with `docker ps` and `docker inspect`

Comment: There's not enough information here by a mile. The problem could equally lie with the image being run rather than the docker commands used to invoke it.

Comment: What `It should display something in the browser as localhost.` mean? What you expect? Add a minimal example which could reproduce.

Comment: @Dusan Gligoric results above.

Comment: I see your command is `/boot/bootloader`, are you sure that one spins up web server? can you please verify on the container that its listening at all for those ports?

Comment: @Dusan Gligoric

When `docker exec -it 280b7062acb3 /bin/bash`

I get `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345`


In browser:
`localhost:80` - displays information that something is wrong and needs improvement.
`localhost:8080` - loading forever
`localhost:8090` - 502 Bad gateway

 on machine (not container): `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN'
'tcp 0  0 127:0:0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0  0 127:0:0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp6 0  0 :::80   :* LISTEN
tcp6 0  0 :::8080   :* LISTEN
tcp6 0  0 ::1:631   :* LISTEN
tcp6 0  0 :::8090   :* LISTEN`

Comment: Can you share your Dockerbuild file for your image?

Comment: @Dusan Gligoric How can I do this? Is this the file above (dockerps.txt)?